# Drop out the N-th element from a list and display its value in a variable

Tags: prolog

I have a predicate `drop_at(X, L, N, R)` which should drop out the N-th element
`X` from a list `L`. The variable `X` is bound to the value of the N-th element,
and `R` is instantiated to the resulted list.

For exemple:

```
?− drop_at(X, [a, b, c, d], 2, R).
X = b
R = [a, c, d]
```

How could i implement both dropping out the element, and also bounding it to a variable X?

For now i can delete n-th element using this:

```
drop([],_,[],_).
drop([_|Xs],N,Ys,1) :- 
    drop(Xs,N,Ys,N).
drop([X|Xs],N,[X|Ys],K) :- 
    K > 1, 
    K1 is K - 1, 
    drop(Xs,N,Ys,K1).
```

But it deletes each N element, which is not what i wanted.

After some more tries i've got to this:

```
drop(1,[_|T],T).
drop(P,[X|Y],[X|R]):-
    P1 is P-1,
    drop(P1,Y,R).
```

But this is still not what i was looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
drop_at(_, [], _, []).     % list is empty, nothing to do
drop_at(H, [H|T], 1, T).   % we've found the right item
drop_at(X, [H|T], N, [H|T2]) :-  % not there yet, recurse
  N > 1,
  N2 is N - 1,
  drop_at(X, T, N2, T2).
```